# How to get average of a Column Based on dates

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still a newbie at this but I am trying to build a VB Macro to provide me with the Average Bet Value per session. Basically I have a list of Dates in Cell 'AD' and also a list of Bet Values in Cell 'AE'.

I am finding a difficulty in coding VB to calculate :

1. From Col 'AD' which contains the dates I need to loop through the dates and if there is a 10 minute difference between a date and an other, then both dates will be considered as a start and end date.
2. Following Step number 1. I need to get the Bet values which fall between the Start and End date and get the average of that session in Col 'AF'
3. Last but not least I need to do this process for all the dates in Col 'AD' - for every session identified we get the average bet value in col AF'

I have pasted the code on how I generated Col AD and Col AE and a snip of the data I am using.

I hope i explained myself well and would like to thank you all

[Excel Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qxt3.png)

```
Public Sub GetDebitValue()

    RowCounter = 1

    Profile.Range("AE1").Value = "BET VALUE"
    Profile.Range("AD1").Value = "BET TIME AND DATE"
    Profile.Range("AF1").Value = "SESSION BET AVERAGE"

    'Range Col 'H2' Contained the action types called Debit which are considered as bets - if value is debit take the bet amount from Col 'C'
    If Profile.Range("H2").Value = "debit" Then
        Profile.Range("C2" + CStr(RowCounter + 1)).Value = Profile.Range("C2" + CStr(RowCounter)).Value
    'Set Date
        Profile.Range("AD2").Value = Profile.Range("I2").Value
    'Set Value
        Profile.Range("AE2").Value = Profile.Range("C2").Value
    End If


    'Always start with debit
    Do
        Select Case Profile.Range("H" + CStr(RowCounter)).Value
            Case "debit"
                Profile.Range("AE" + CStr(RowCounter + 1)).Value = Profile.Range("C" + CStr(RowCounter)).Value
                'Copy Date
                Profile.Range("AD" + CStr(RowCounter + 1)).Value = Profile.Range("I" + CStr(RowCounter)).Value
            Case Else
                'Do Nothing
        End Select

        If Profile.Range("A" + CStr(RowCounter + 1)).Value = CStr("") Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        'Call GamblingLength
        RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
    Loop Until RowCounter = 99999
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your qusetion and provide a proper example data. Also see [mcve] for how to provide a good example. Your screenshot was not included, please try to upload it again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could do this using a few helper columns and some SUMIF formula and not even need VBA. But then you could use VBA to automate it and get rid of helper columns etc. Do you have some sample data?

Comment: Updated the Snip of the data used on excel. Unfortunately I couldn't mate a sample data as an excel file. Hope this helps though.

@jamheadart to be honest it would be easier doing it with Formulas but less efficient for the type of work I'm using. As you said automation helps and leave a clean interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I knocked this up quickly, I didn't have time to recreate your exact conditions and figure out some bits of the code but I hope you can use this generic pattern to achieve the steps:

The data starts on row FOUR here (row 3 is the headers)

[image]

And the code to achieve this was:

```
Sub avgs()
Dim i As Long ' row counter
Dim c As Long ' average divisor counter
Dim cTot As Double ' cumulative value total
With Sheet2
    c = 1 ' initiate count as 1
    cTot = .Range("B4").Value2 ' initiate cumulative total as first row of data val
    For i = 5 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' cycle through to end row
        If .Range("A" & i).Value2 - .Range("A" & i - 1).Value2 < 0.00694 Then
            ' if less than ten minute gap on this row then add to both avg div and tot counter 
            c = c + 1
            cTot = cTot + .Range("B" & i).Value2
        Else
            ' else set the value in column c and reset the avg div and tot counter
            .Range("C" & i - 1).Value2 = cTot / c
            c = 1
            cTot = .Range("B" & i).Value2
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```